# Applying (Reclaiming) French Schengen Visa without My Old Passports and Information about my Old Visa

Tags: passports, schengen-visas, applications, lost-documents

I am a Chinese Citizen living in the United Kingdom at the moment. My previous passport containing a valid French Schengen Tourism Visa stolen in June. Having observed other thread it seems that the only option I left is to get a new visa through a brand new application (if you can kindly confirm this that would be much appreciated!)

However, while I was trying to using the online application system for French visa Application I was required to enter my previous visa issuances including the valid dates. Sadly I don't have copies for them and the original visas were lost along with my stolen passport hence it seemed unlikely I can complete this part. I just wonder what should I do at this stage? Should I proceed with the application as if I haven't received any Schengen visa in the past five years (even though I indeed got 3 of them)?

If not, as the online application system is quite ambiguous on the contact I can make, in order to address my application issue should I contact the TLS or contact the French embassy itself?

Comment: Is there space on the form to add a comment or any possibility to attach a letter? I would recommend addressing the issue/mentioning the previous visas even if you cannot find the details instead of omitting them entirely. TLS is unlikely to be helpful with anything out of the ordinary but the French consulate is usually difficult to get hold of (they use TLS precisely not to have to deal with inquiries from the public).

Comment: You should enter as much information as you can remember. I don't think they will care if you get a date wrong by some days or weeks. If the system will not let you proceed without entering e.g. a serial number or code that you really cannot remember then just enter something clearly bogus, like "0000" or "XXX".

Comment: Also to clarify if I knew that my last submission of French Visa was on March 7th, 2018 and the Visa was ”returned for collection“ on March 9th, 2018 as stated in my mailboxes. Would this suggest that the issuing date being March 8th, 2018 and given the 2 year length of my visa the expiry date being March 7th, 2020?